# JavaScript-интерфейс перемещения "карточек" между "лотками"

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, интерфейс, drag-n-drop

Нужно сделать такой интерфейс на `JavaScript`:

[image: Изображение нужного интерфейса]

Суть проста: Есть лотки, внутри которых карточки с фамилиями, пользователь хватает любую карточку и перетаскивает её в любой лоток, после нажимает на кнопку "*Сохранить*", и я в `PHP` получаю массив лотков с вложенными массивами карточек внутри.

Может кто-нибудь подскажет готовую библиотеку `JavaScript` или еще лучше плагин `JQuery`?

В стандартном `JqueryUI` есть [`Droppable`](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/), но допиливать много придется, а хотелось бы что-то более близкое к задаче и полуготовое.

Comment: Почему много? достаточно добавить поле в БД и сделать аякс запрос к `php` скрипту, который сохранит в бд при перемещении. Не так много

Comment: В html5 есть drag-n-drop. Может, перетаскивать карточку с ее div в другой, и при этом событии менять значение ее нумерации нахождения. Когда "сохранить" нажата, просто передать обновленный список лотков с их карточками позиций карточек... Т.е. такой список может быть простым массивом джаваскрипт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элементу с фамилией требуется указывать фамилию в атрибуте **data-lname**. Из этих атрибутов будет использовано значение для составления массивов, которые будут отправлены через AJAX. В конструкции AJAX требуется указать **url** для получения данных в массиве **$_POST** на стороне сервера.

Работу можно посмотреть здесь **[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/oco1b2h2/9/).**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    // Присваиваем функционал лоткам
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();

    // при клике на "Сохранить" собираем данные из ul с классом 'connectedSortable'
    $('#saveSortableLists').click(function(event) {
      var output = []; // массив, в который будем добавлять массивы со списками
      $('.connectedSortable').each(function(index) {
        output[index] = $(this).sortable('toArray', {
          attribute: 'data-lname'
        });
      });

      console.log(output); // [Array[3], Array[2]]

      // Отправляем запрос на сервер и передаем output
      $.ajax({
        url: "send.php", // Куда отправляем запрос пост
        type: "POST",
        data: output,
      }).done(function(response) {
        // код, который будет выполнен после ответа сервера
        console.log(response) // Выводим в консоль результат
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Лоток 1</td>
        <td>Лоток 2</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default" data-lname="Иванов">Иванов</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" data-lname="Сидоров">Сидоров</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" data-lname="Петров">Петров</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
          <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
            <li class="ui-state-highlight" data-lname="Малеев">Малеев</li>
            <li class="ui-state-highlight" data-lname="Орлов">Орлов</li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" id="saveSortableLists">Сохранить</button>
</body>
```

Ответ на вопрос @Escalion:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  // Присваиваем функционал лоткам
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function() {
      var output = []; // массив, в который будем добавлять массивы со списками
      $('.connectedSortable').each(function(index) {
        output[index] = $(this).sortable('toArray', {
          attribute: 'data-lname'
        });
      });

      console.log(output); // [Array[3], Array[2]]

      // Отправляем запрос на сервер и передаем output
      $.ajax({
      url: "send.php", // Куда отправляем запрос пост
      type: "POST",
      data: output,
    }).done(function(response) {
      // код, который будет выполнен после ответа сервера
      console.log(response) // Выводим в консоль результат
    });
  }
  }).disableSelection();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Отличный пример! А как сделать так, чтобы не нужно было подтверждать кнопкой, а сразу после переноса запускалась функция считывания порядка элементов и ajax запрос?

Comment: Смотрите в сообщении "Ответ на вопрос @Escalion:"